# I can't get any output and my statements don't execute properly because of this, however, every if statement does execute even when it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to write a program that multiples four numbers and outputs their sign whether if the answer is a negative or a positive number. I had to write the program using a logical operator but the thing is that I wanted to try first using a simple if statement series while also using relational operators. I wrote this code, and checked it multiple times, the code compiles and executes but shows no output. It says "The answer is " followed by a blank space and shows all 3 of my if statements. Can someone please kindly fix my code for me (and possibly tell me how to write such a program using logical operators where I give 4 inputs and I get the output saying if the answer after multiplying the 4 numbers is positive or negative, and if is there any way to do that without actually calculating aka multiplying) and tell me what exactly is wrong with my code. The code is given here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program746
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b, c, d;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number:");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number:");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the third number:");
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the fourth number:");
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int e = a * b * c * d; 
            if (e < 0) ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result is negative and has the '-' sign ");
            }

            if (e > 0) ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result is positive and has the'+' sign");
            }

            if (e == 0) ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result is zero, and does not have a sign");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is ", e);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: VTC as typo. Remove the semicolons after the `if`s

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b, c, d;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number:");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number:");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the third number:");
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the fourth number:");
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int e = a * b * c * d;
            if (e < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result is negative and has the '-' sign ");
            }

            if (e > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result is positive and has the'+' sign");
            }

            if (e == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The result is zero, and does not have a sign");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", e);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: run this code and everything will be fine!

Comment: Furqan Sab, thankyou for your help, however I want to ask if is there any way of writing a program that takes 4 inputs and tells if their product is positive or negative without actually multiplying them, I was told that it can be done using logical operators but I can't seems to figure out how :/

Answer (score 0):

Delete the semicolon after each if statement. Because with a semicolon at the end you terminate the if.
You can check out this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3508c3a2-fd1c-49db-93ea-f7bb5c2d27f4/extra-semicolon-suberst-conditional-flow?forum=csharpgeneral

Your if:

```
if (e < 0) ;
{
    ...
}
```

Correct if:

```
if (e < 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Instead of using four ReadLines, you could do a for loop with i = 4 and multiply each number to a result int or save them in a int array.

I would write the program like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = PrintSign(4);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The answer is {0}", result));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int PrintSign(int maxNumbers)
    {
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxNumbers; i++)
        {
            int number = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Please enter number {0}:", i));
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
                    break;
            }

            // if one number is zero, return 0 (multiply with zero and it's zero all the time)
            if (number == 0)
                return 0;
            result *= number;
        }

        // check for negative number
        if (result < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("The result is negative and has the '-' sign");
        // else, because zero is not possible at this point
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The result is positive and has the'+' sign");

        return result;
    }
```

Please like and accept the answer if this answered your question :)

Comment: OP should also note that **[the compiler tried to warn them about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0642)** - _"Possible mistaken empty statement. A semicolon after a conditional statement may cause your code to execute differently than intended."_

Comment: Thanks sir it did help fix my issue, but my other question is if there is another way to write the same program using logical operators also, that program should not calculate the 4 numbers to tell if a number is positive or negative? Help would be appreciated :)